# AS2 function to JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, actionscript

This is the AS function I've got. Was not developed by me. 
The goal is to create the same function in Javascript. The external URL targets an ASP file, not an XML, that's my problem.

---

var newsArray:Array = new Array();
function loadNews(tipo) {

```
xml = "http://www.promored.com/new/modulo-xml/xml_noticias.asp?tipo="+tipo+"&publicaAgencia=S"; 
trace(xml);

function loadXML(){
    cant = this.firstChild.childNodes.length;       

    for (var i = 0; i<cant; i++) {
        var dato = docXML.firstChild.childNodes[i];
        var titulo = dato.attributes.titulo;            
        var texto = dato.attributes.texto;

        newsArray.push({
            titulo:titulo,
            texto:texto
        });         
    }

    delete docXML;
    if (miArray.length>0) {
        gotoAndStop("cargado");
    } else {
        nextFrame();
    }
}
var docXML = new XML();
docXML.ignoreWhite = true;
docXML.onLoad = cargaXML;
docXML.load(xml);
```

}
loadNews(tipo);

---

This is the JS simple function, works only if the URL were an XML extension.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "xml",
  url: "xml/noticias.xml",
  success: function(xml){
      $(xml).find("noticia").each(function(){
        $('.news-title').append($(this).attr('titulo'));
        $('.news-text').append($(this).attr('texto'));            
    });
  }
});
```

Any help would be welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: The url does not have to end with `.xml` as long as the response is valid xml - that's all that matters.  Can you show us the response, or give us a working url for the request?

Comment: Are you not setting the content type on the server?

Comment: The URL is: 
"http://www.promored.com/new/modulo-xml/xml_noticias.asp?tipo="+tipo+"&publicaAgencia=S"

The XML file extension on the Js function, was a test on my local machine, to read a similar content of the original file.

Comment: I can see that url in your code above, but without a valid value for `tipo` it's not use to us.

Comment: Can you either supply us with a fully working url (with a value for `tipo`), or post the xml so we can see it?  Without one of those we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me even if the target file have php extension.

Maybe try this:

```
$.post("xml/noticias.xml", function(xml){
  $(xml).find("noticia").each(function(){
    $('.news-title').append($(this).attr('titulo'));
    $('.news-text').append($(this).attr('texto'));            
  });
},"xml");
```

and let me know if that works.